# sprite kit: imageNamed: or texture:?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode, sktexture, imagenamed

I am currently working on a simple 2d sprite kit game. When I created the background "image" object I initialized it using the SKSpriteNode convenience imageNamed: initializer. However, after looking through some of the spriteKit documentation I found that it is also possible to set the "image" of the background sprite by using a texture instead with the texture: initializer.

**I was wondering which one is the best for my scenario, and in general, where to use one over the other.**

Here is the code I currently am using- `backgroundImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "BackgroundImage")`

Here is the code I could use instead with the texture: initializer- 
`var backgroundTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed:"BackgroundImage")
backgroundImage = SKSpriteNode(texture: backgroundTexture)`

Comment: May this one helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19063796/confusion-skspritenode-sktexture-difference

Comment: thanks this is what I was looking for!